# Can't convert html.erb's to haml with the "erb2haml" gem on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, haml

## Solved. Look at my answer below.

My Problem: I just can't convert all my html.erb's to haml. I tried the erb2haml gem with the "rake haml:replace_erbs" command but it doesn't work. Here is the full error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Ruby>rake haml:replace_erbs --trace
** Invoke haml:replace_erbs (first_time)
** Execute haml:replace_erbs
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - which html2haml
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/erb2haml-0.1.5/lib/erb2haml/railties/erb2haml.rake:46:in ``'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/erb2haml-0.1.5/lib/erb2haml/railties/erb2haml.rake:46:in `block (2 levels) i
n <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => haml:replace_erbs
```

It seems that the gem tries to use the "which" command on my Windows machine, what wouldn't make sense because it doesn't exist on Windows. Is there maybe a way to replace the linux/mac "which" command with the Windows "where" command ? If not, is there a other way to replace all html.erbs to haml's at once ?

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

*- Moe*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really easy and good way. First install the "haml-rails" gem if you haven't already, then just insert

```
rake haml:erb2haml
```

in the Console. It converts all .erb views into .haml .
Works very fast and flawless.

~ Cheers